# Flutter: How to switch from one page view to another?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter app where I have a screen which contains a PageView Builder.There are two other screens which are shown depending on the condition in the PageView Builder(i.e. QuizResult and QuizQuestion).

If the index if equal to the number of quiz questions it will show the Quiz Result Page otherwise it will continue showing the next question on the QuizQuestion Page(Have hardcoded the question for this example).

I want to know what logic can I add in the FlatButton widget onPressed in the QuizResult Page so that I can reset the index of the PageView back to the start and can again show the QuizQuestion Page again?

**This is the QuizScreen**

```
class QuizScreen extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: state.controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == quiz.questions.length) {
                return QuizResult();
            } else { 
                return QuizQuestion(question: quiz.questions[index]);
            }
        },
        )
    );
}
}
```

**The QuizQuestion Widget looks like this**

```
class QuizQuestion extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Scaffold(body: Text('Which is the fastest animal?'));

}
}
```

**The QuizResult  Widget looks like this**

```
class QuizResult extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(body: FlatButton(onPressed(){ < Logic Here ?? >}, child:Text('PlayAgain')));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code to reproduce the issue and then modified it for readability.

All you need is to assign an `itemCount`. And it needs to be the `length of the quiz plus one`. We need to add one more page to show the `result` page.

```
itemCount: questions.length + 1,
```

As you already predicted, we need to check the `index` of the shown page and create a `condition` based on it.

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  if (index == questions.length) {
    return QuizResult(onPressed: onPressed);
  }

  return QuizQuestion(question: questions[index]);
},
```

Lastly, you need to jump to the `first page` using the `controller` to reset the quiz. The easiest way to do that is: Passing the `onPressed` function via constructor to `QuizResult`:

```
void onPressed() {
  controller.jumpToPage(0);
  currentPage = 0;
}
```

Please check the following solution:

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const QuizScreen(),
      );
}

class QuizScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuizScreen> createState() => _QuizScreenState();
}

class _QuizScreenState extends State<QuizScreen> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<String> questions = [
    'Which is the fastest animal?',
    'Which is the slowest animal?',
    'Which is the longest animal?',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: PageView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: controller,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: questions.length + 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index == questions.length) {
                      return QuizResult(onPressed: onPressed);
                    }

                    return QuizQuestion(question: questions[index]);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (currentPage == questions.length) return;

                  controller.jumpToPage(++currentPage);
                },
                child: const Text('Next'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  void onPressed() {
    controller.jumpToPage(0);
    currentPage = 0;
  }
}

class QuizQuestion extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuizQuestion({Key? key, required this.question}) : super(key: key);

  final String question;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Center(
        child: Text(question),
      );
}

class QuizResult extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuizResult({Key? key, required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final void Function() onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: const Text('Play Again'),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

You can access the modified source code through [GitHub](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72510623).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.